# Вычислить высоты треугольника

Tags: qbasic

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу с использованием QBasic: в треугольнике АВС А=8см, В=4см, С=6см. Надо найти все высоты треугольника.
    Пока что я только смог найти площадь по теореме Герона.

```
INPUT "Введите стороны треугольника"; a, b, c
DIM per AS INTEGER
DIM halfper AS INTEGER
per = a + b + c
halfper = per / 2
S = Sqr(halfper * (halfper - a) * (halfper - b) * (halfper - c))
```

Что делать дальше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть площадь, высота равна удвоенной площади, делённой на длину противолежащей стороны.

Дерзайте!

---

ЗЫ: Зря вы используете `Integer` для сторон и периметра, `Double` гораздо каноничнее.